# Why does mounting a route in Rails fail with "uninitialized constant API"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, ruby-grape

I am working on an app that includes an `API` that is using the `grape` gem.

Here is my `Root` Class:

```
module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    rescue_from :all do |e|
      Rack::Response.new(
        [ "Error: #{e.message}" ],
        500,
        { "Content-type" => "text/error" }
      ).finish
    end

    prefix "api"
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json
    error_format :json

    mount ::API::ServiceRequests
  end
end
```

Here is how I am mounting it in routes:

`mount API::Root => '/'`

The error I am receiving is:
`routes.rb:45:in`block in ': uninitialized constant API (NameError)`

The files are structured like `app/api/root.rb` and I have this bit of code in my `application.rb` to load in the files:

```
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
```

Answer (score 15):

Try moving your API code's files from `app/api` to `app/api/api`.

From [Grape's documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape#rails):

> Place API files into `app/api`. Rails expects a subdirectory that matches the name of the Ruby module and a file name that matches the name of the class. In our example, the file name location and directory for `Twitter::API` should be `app/api/twitter/api.rb`.

Thus the correct location for your `API::Root` class would actually be `app/api/api/root.rb`.

Comment: I have been scratching my head for a day around the same issue as OP, thanks for the answer! I had `app/api/v1/my_endpoint` prefixed as `API::V1::MyEndpoint`. Moving it to `app/api/api/v1/my_endpoint` solved my problem. This seems pretty srange to me, but I guess this shows I should give a more specific name to the api, like `app/api/github/v1/my_endpoint` or `app/api/google/v1/my_endpoint`, etc.